# Python yield vs Ruby yield

Tags: python, ruby, yield

In Ruby, the yield keyword is used to yield to closures for blocks of execution.

How does this keyword differ in the Python language?

Comment: I'd answer but I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python) covers it

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**In ruby**, yield is a shortcut that is used to call an anonymous function.  Ruby has a special syntax for passing an anonymous function to a method; the syntax is known as a `block`.  Because the function has no name, you use the name *yield* to call the function:

```
def do_stuff(val)
  puts "Started executing do_stuff"
  yield(val+3)
  yield(val+4) 
  puts "Finshed executing do_stuff" 
end

do_stuff(10) {|x| puts x+3} #<= This is a block, which is an anonymous function
                            #that is passed as an additional argument to the 
                            #method do_stuff

--output:--
Started executing do_stuff
16
17
Finshed executing do_stuff
```

**In python**, when you see yield inside a function definition, that means that the function is a `generator`.  A generator is a special type of function that can be stopped mid execution and restarted.  Here's an example:

```
def do_stuff(val):
    print("Started execution of do_stuff()")

    yield val + 3
    print("Line after 'yield val + 3'")
    yield val + 4
    print("Line after 'yield val + 4'")

    print("Finished executing do_stuff()")


my_gen = do_stuff(10)

val = next(my_gen)    
print("--received {} from generator".format(val))
```

output:

```
Started execution of do_stuff()
--received 13 from generator
```

More code:

```
val = next(my_gen)    
print("--received {} from generator".format(val))
```

output:

```
Line after 'yield val + 3'
--received 14 from generator
```

From the output, you can see that `yield` causes a result to be returned; then execution is immediately halted.  When you call next() again on the generator, execution continues until the next yield statement is encountered, which returns a value, then execution halts again.

Comment: Basically, Python's `yield` keyword is equivalent to Ruby's `Enumerator::Yielder#yield`.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know about the Enumerator::Yielder class!!

Comment: For some more details on `Enumerator::Yielder` and `Enumerator::Generator` I recommend: http://patshaughnessy.net/2013/4/3/ruby-2-0-works-hard-so-you-can-be-lazy

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, **yield** is used to bounce control to block( like anonymous function) to execute the block's statements and then bounce back to where the block's called.

With `yield args` you can pass arguments to the block, and also with `lvar = yield`
you can get whatever returned and bind it to **lvar** after control exits the block. It's a much general and consistent feature design in Ruby. And of course,
you can apply this idea to iterating over collections.

Whereas in Python, mostly people use **yield** to facilitate effective access of items over somewhat collection,  they focus on **iterate once and generate on the fly once being called** idea, which is the main use of **yield** in Python.

FYI, It's not quite a distinguished feature between Python and Ruby on **yield**, at least on the way to use it. (Apparently they are implemented differently, as for python, **yield** creates a generator, which will not run any code unless the iteration starts). For example, the way **yield** is used in python contextmanager is quite the same in Ruby.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
@contextmanager
def openfile(name, mode):
    f= open(name, mode)
    yield f
    f.close()

with openfile('log.txt', 'r') as handle:
    for line in handle:
        print line
```

here, **yield** pass **file** handle to **with**, and execute **with-statements** exactly **once** and then bounce back to file close statement