# Porting from Ruby to Python: What to do with 'yield'

Tags: python, ruby, language-comparisons

I currently try to port a piece of code from Ruby to Python to do a bit algorithm research. I have no experience in Ruby and don't know how to handle the 'yield' keyword.

The code is for a *Myers diff algorithm* and fully described in this [blog](https://blog.jcoglan.com/2017/02/17/the-myers-diff-algorithm-part-3/)

This is the code snippet I don't understand:

```
  while x > prev_x and y > prev_y
    yield x - 1, y - 1, x, y
    x, y = x - 1, y - 1
  end
```

Is there a way to approximate this in Python?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3066703/10077

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost identically. Though the semantics of Python's and Ruby's `yield` is somewhat different, in this case they coincide almost exactly.

Ruby's `yield` invokes a block that is passed into the function, giving it its parameters.

Python's `yield` makes the function a generator, and generates one output from it.

---

Both of them only make sense in context of a function, so just your `while` loop is too short a context to use it. But let's take something like it as a simplified example, in Ruby:

```
def numbers_and_doubles(n)
  i = 0
  while i < n
    yield i, 2 * i
    i += 1
  end
end
```

This function accepts a block with one parameter, then generates numbers up to that number along with their double and executes that block with those parameters:

```
numbers_and_doubles(5) do |num, double|
  puts "#{num} * 2 = #{double}"
end
```

As blocks are basically the same thing as callback functions, it is equivalent to this Python:

```
def numbers_and_doubles(n, callback):
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        callback(i, i*2)
        i += 1

def output(num, double):
    print(f"{num} * 2 = {double}")

numbers_and_doubles(5, output)
```

---

On the other hand, Python's `yield` creates a generator - a function that returns a function that can produce values on demand:

```
def numbers_and_doubles(n):
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        yield i, 2 * i
        i += 1
```

The most natural way to consume a generator is via a `for` loop:

```
for num, double in numbers_and_doubles(5):
    print(f"{num} * 2 = {double}")
```

In Ruby, the closest literal translation is `Enumerator`:

```
def numbers_and_doubles(n)
  Enumerator.new do |yielder|
    i = 0
    while i < n
      yielder.yield(i, i*2)
      i += 1
    end
  end
end
```

and the most natural way to consume an `Enumerator` is using `each` (which is what Rubyists prefer over `for`):

```
numbers_and_doubles(5).each do |num, double|
  puts "#{num} * 2 = #{double}"
end
```

---

But, as I said, even though they do something slightly different, the original Ruby above (with `yield`) is surprisingly similar to the original Python above (with `yield`). The way they are consumed is slightly different, but appropriate to each language's idiom.

In your case, if you leave `yield` exactly as it is in your Python, the line that consumes it changes from Ruby's

```
backtrack do |prev_x, prev_y, x, y|
```

to Python's

```
for prev_x, prev_y, x, y in backtrack():
```

You can read more at [Python yield vs Ruby yield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35639401/python-yield-vs-ruby-yield).

---

Note that the most natural way to write this loop is not `while` in either language (I'd use `range` in Python and `times` in Ruby), but I wanted to have code that looks similar for both languages, for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at the code from the blog:

```
def diff
  diff = []

  backtrack do |prev_x, prev_y, x, y|
    a_line, b_line = @a[prev_x], @b[prev_y]

    if x == prev_x
      diff.unshift(Diff::Edit.new(:ins, nil, b_line))
    elsif y == prev_y
      diff.unshift(Diff::Edit.new(:del, a_line, nil))
    else
      diff.unshift(Diff::Edit.new(:eql, a_line, b_line))
    end
  end

  diff
end
```

As we can see the block is passed to the `backtrack` method with four arguments, so theoretically in your implementation of this method you have to pass a callback function to it.